# java method call from javascript in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am new to JSP,
I have method that contains loop and want to display value

```
<%!
private void getDemo() {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        setName("Val: " + i); %>
        <script language="javascript">
            var name = "<%= getName()%>";
            console.log(name);
        </script>
    <%!}
}%>
<%!
String name;
private void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
private String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
%>
```

**Call**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 window.onload=function(){<%getDemo();%>};
</script>
```

**Problem**
But when I see the console, It only display `Val: 9`
How can I achieve all value?  I need Script code inside Java Code. Is it Possible?

Comment: NO. You cannot call script code inside java.. Java is a server side. script code are client side

Comment: but the last value display here...

Comment: In browser you don't see any JSP or java code. What you see is just a plain HTML with Javascript and/or CSS. All these things can just be the output of the JSP/servlet code (not JSP or java itself) which runs on the server.

Comment: @SJnawali when your code runs all the jsp code are run first and then it executes the script code. Read the JSP life cycle http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_life_cycle.htm and also read about jsp tags dont use jsp declaration tag in all your code

Comment: @Dineshkani: yes you are correct...hmm thanks for information.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript runs client side in the browser so will not normally interact with your Java code running server side