# How can I call a function from JSF server in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have this function in `ManageBean` class :

```
public String myname()
{
    return employeeManagedBean.I().getUser_name();
}
```

I want to call this function in a JavaScript function and catch the returned value from `Myname` function.  I tried this :

```
<h:form>
   <p:remoteCommand name="myname" actionListener="#{employeeManagedBean.myname()}"  />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage() {
            var m = myname();
            console.log(m);
        }
    </script>    
</h:form>
```

but the value of `m` that printed in the console was `undefined`.
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: `myname` is not defined because JavaScript is not JSF. JSF is a server sided language. You'll have to use XHR to get that value into JS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784322/java-method-call-from-javascript-in-jsp-page

Comment: Please ignore the link in above comment of Sterling. JSF != JSP.

Comment: I know JavaScript is not a server side ,but I read that primefaces support this feature by "remoteCommand " tag

Comment: Note : when I wrote "var m = myname() " that mean I want to call the name of remoteCommand which has an action to call myname  function in server side .

Comment: I am working on JSF server not jsp and i want to call managed bean function not to pass properties , Why does my question marked as duplicate ? @SterlingArcher